# ¿ViewModel compartir datos entre dos o mas Activity

Tags: java, activity, viewmodel

Lo que quiero hacer es que en un activity haga una operacion digamos una calculadora, en el activity1 esta la calculadora por ejemplo: hago la operacion de suma de dos numero 5 + 5 el resultado es 10 eso esta guardodo en el ViewModel yo salgo de la aplicacion y dentro y mantiene los datos pero cuando entro al activity2 y quiero mostra el resultado que esta guardodo en el activity1 no me carga se reinicia el ViewModel.

¿se puede conservar los datos del ViowModel del Activity1 para luego cargarlo usar el mismo ViewModel en el activity2?

Podria pasarlo como itent.putExtra pero si se puede hacer con el ViewModel seria mejor

***codigo:***

> Activity1

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding .inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        resultado = binding.total;
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getTotal().observe(this, aDouble ->
                resultado.setText(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(aDouble))
                ));
        B1 = binding.botonSuma;
        B2 = binding.botonResta;
        B3 = binding.botonMulti;
        B4 = binding.botonDivi;
        nuevo = binding.activitydos;
     //  String nu1 = n1.getText().toString();
     //  String nu2 = n2.getText().toString();
       nuevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent itent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModelDosActivity2.class);
               startActivity(itent);
           }
       });
        B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String  nu1 = binding.n1.getText().toString();
                String nu2 = binding.n2.getText().toString();
                viewModel.operacion(nu1,nu2,1);
            }
        });
        B2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String  nu1 = binding.n1.getText().toString();
                String nu2 = binding.n2.getText().toString();
                 viewModel.operacion(nu1,nu2,2);
            }
        });
        B3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String  nu1 = binding.n1.getText().toString();
                String nu2 = binding.n2.getText().toString();
                 viewModel.operacion(nu1,nu2,3);
            }
        });
        B4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String  nu1 = binding.n1.getText().toString();
                String nu2 = binding.n2.getText().toString();
                  viewModel.operacion(nu1,nu2,4);
            }
        });
```

> ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<Double> total = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MainViewModel(){
        resetTotal();
    }
    public MutableLiveData<Double> getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    void resetTotal(){
        total.setValue(0.0);
    }
    public void operacion(String n1, String n2, int operador){
        double nu1 = Double.parseDouble(n1),nu2 = Double.parseDouble(n2);
        // 1 suma, 2 resta,3 multiplicion, 4 divi
        if (operador == 1){
            total.setValue(nu1 + nu2);
        }
        else if (operador == 2){
            total.setValue(nu1 - nu2);
        }
        else if (operador == 3){
            total.setValue(nu1 * nu2);
        }
        else if (operador == 4){
            total.setValue(nu1 / nu2);
        }
    }
}
```

> Actifity2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityModelDos2Binding binding = ActivityModelDos2Binding .inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        resultado = binding.total;
        viewModel.getTotal().observe(this, aDouble ->
                resultado.setText(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(aDouble))
                ));
    }
```

cuando cargo el ViewModel en el Actifity2 se pone en 0 pero al regresar al Activity1 mantiene el resultado y quiero que mantenga el resultado tambien cuando lo llame en el Activity2.

estoy aprendiendo a programar en java asique espero me entienda mi codigo gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El problema es que estás intentando guardar el resultado en el viewModel y compartirlo con otras vistas... el viewModel tiene datos de una vista en particular, no tiene datos de tu aplicación en general. De hecho, cuando creas el viewModel lo haces a partir de la clase en la que te encuentras, y además instancias uno nuevo en el onCreate... cómo va a tener los mismos datos en dos clases partiendo de estas bases? Si quieres compartir datos entre varias clases deberías crear un servicio que funcione de caché para almacenar lo que necesitas, y que será de dónde saquen los datos tu viewModels

Comment: Gracias pense que se podia compartir el ViewModel con otras actividades pero creo que no, gracias por aclarar mi duda.

Comment: Lo extraño es que creas necesitar dos `Activity` distintas para esto. ¿Por qué crees que necesitas dos `Activity`? Si implementas una arquitectura limpia, puedes hacer todo desde un Fragment. El ViewModel en ese caso te conectará con la capa de datos a través de un Repositorio en el cual se desarrollará toda la lógica, por ejemplo, determinar si hay datos en local, si no los hay buscarlos en remoto, etc. Te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture?hl=es-419) las veces que sea, hasta tener claro el sentido de la arquitectura propuesta por Android.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte se agradese A. Cedano